# How to print out empty nodes in array instead of getting the address of nodes in an array

Tags: python, arrays, class

## why do i get an output of the addresses within an array instead of getting ['','','','','','','',''] instead? How do i get it to output ['','','','','','','',''] instead of the address of the nodes?

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, Name, Pointer =-1):
    #-1 represents null value
    self.__name = Name
    self.__pointer = Pointer

  def getName(self):
    return self.__name
  
  def getPointer(self):
    return self.__pointer
  

  #need setName and setPointer as __ means that u can only change the attributes inside the class
  def setName(self, Name):
    self.__name = Name
  
  def setPointer(self, Pointer):
    self.__pointer = Pointer

class Linkedlist:
  def __init__(self, size):
    self.__Make = [Node('') for i in range (size)]

  def getMake(self):
    return self.__Make

x = Linkedlist(8)
print(x.getMake())
```

Answer (score 0):

You created nodes by `x.getMake()`, but you didn't set the node names.

You should first set the node names:

```
x = Linkedlist(8)
nodes = x.getMake()

for i, node in enumerate(nodes):
    node.setName(Name=str(i))
```

Then you can print:

```
for node in nodes:
    print(node.getName())
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```